# Serve an Angular library live from an external source

Tags: angular, typescript

We have a distributed Angular team for a big project, and each team design and develop a different component, with its surrounding service/models, on a common subset of interfaces/classes/services. All those components respect the same pattern. Those components are then released using ng-packagr to an intern NPM registry and installed into the main app that use them.

However, this implies to redeploy the full app every time a changes occur on one of the subproject, and a downtime of the whole.

We are looking, if possible, of a way to redeploy independently those components. Like, if it is possible to load an external module at runtime and use it then.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Depends on your tool chain and development workflow